# CodeIgniter form validation radio button not working

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-form-validation

I have a form with 3 radio buttons. The IDs are unique in the form, and all three have the same name, namely "vehicle_type". The radio buttons are generated correctly when I do source view

```
<input type="radio" name="vehicle_type" id="type_vehicle" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="vehicle_type" id="type_trailer" value="2" checked>
<input type="radio" name="vehicle_type" id="type_plant" value="3">
```

I have no validation rule set for the radio group, yet my form complains that the field is required.

I can confirm that there is no validation rule by running:

```
echo $this->form_validation->has_rule('vehicle_type');
```

It indicates no validation. Using that call on another field, i.e., client_name, returns "boolean: 1"

Why would the field try to validate if there is no validation rule set?

**EDIT**

I am using Wiredesignz HMVC in my project, so the Form_validation class is extended.

```
        if ($this->form_validation->run($this)) {
            $test = do_file_upload($post_data);
        } else {
            var_dump(validation_errors()); 

            // echos "The Vehicle type field is required"
        }
```

This problem only occurs with radio buttons:

All other forms without radio buttons validate correctly using the same check: `($this->form_validation->run($this)`

My form validation is set with this function:

```
public function set_form_validation_rules($data)
{
    foreach ($data as $field) {
        if (!empty($field['validation']['rules'])) {
            if (!is_array($field['validation']['rules'])) {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules($field['name'], $field['label'], $field['validation']['rules']);
            } else {
                foreach ($field['validation']['rules'] as $fv) {
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules($field['name'], $field['label'], $fv);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the radio button is defined as:

```
        $data['fields']['type_plant'] = [
            'name' => 'vehicle_type',
            'id' => 'type_plant',
            'input_class' => 'input-group width-100',
            'color' => 'red',
            'value' => 3,
            'validation' => '',
            'checked' => ($posts['vehicle_type'] == 3)
        ];
```

The other two radio buttons in the group are the same, just have different values and IDs.

Comment: Care to [edit] the question and include the controller function that processes the submit?

Comment: Done. I am 100% sure I do the validation correctly. All other forms validate correctly, and the check if it validates is exactly the same: `$this->form_validation->run($this)`. If I take radio buttons out, the form validates correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but I was interested in seeing the rules, etc. for form_validation too.

Comment: I set them in a function. Editing the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('vehicle_type', 'Vehicle type', 'required');
```

Answer (score 0):

Load library for form validation and other helpers in `application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');

$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url');
```

In your controller file :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('vehicle_type', 'Vehicle Type', 'required');
```

In your view file use below code for printing validation errors

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers given above tells me how to use form validation. It is not what I requested. I am far beyond that - as they all worked, except for radio buttons. As it turns out, passing the validation array incorrectly to the function in the `$data` array. Once I passed the data correctly, the form validation also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Bro Try this maybe it can help
This method is very simple
In form

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="vehicle_type" class="col-sm-3 control-label">vehicle</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                          <label><input type="radio" name="vehicle_type" id="vehicle_type" value="1"> ONE </label>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                          <label><input type="radio" name="vehicle_type" value="2"> TWO </label>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                          <label><input type="radio" name="vehicle_type" value="3"> THREE </label>
                       </div>
                       <small class="info help-block"></small>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

Set Your Controller

```
    public function add_save(){
    
      if ($this->input->post('vehicle_type') == "1"){   
        
      }else if($this->input->post('vehicle_type') == "2"){
        
      }else if($this->input->post('vehicle_type') == "3"){
        
      }else{
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('vehicle_type', 'Vehicle', 'required');
      }
    

      if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    
          $save = [
              'vehicle_type' => $this->input->post('vehicle_type')
        ];

          $this->model_yourmoderl->add($save);
        

      } else {
          $this->data['errors'] = $this->form_validation->error_array();
      }

      $this->response($this->data);
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).